# Creating form to apply get variable

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a number HTML 5 field and a button next to it. After typing in some number, user clicks a button, and the number is set as a `$_GET['number']` variable on the same website.

How can I do that?

I don't wanna do this using redirections (form tag etc.). Is it possible to do something like aria controls here? Something like:

```
<select userId="select_user_type" name="dyntable_length" size="1" aria-controls="dyntable" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="path1"></option>
    <option value="path2"></option>
</select>
```

But with number field and after clicking a button?

Comment: This depends on what you want to do with the value. If you need database transactions you will have to use ajax. If you want to change something on the page, this can be done with just JavaScript.

Comment: The only thing I wanna do is to add/change get parameter and reload a page, that's it.

Comment: But you don't want to reload the page via a form? Then you will need to use ajax calls to a php file.

Comment: I want to do exacly like I did it with select (see my post), but instead of onchange and getting option's value, I wanna do this onclick with getting field's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
$("#button").click(function(e) {
    var number = $('#number').val();
    $.ajax({
        url : 'http://example.com',
        type: "POST",
        data : { number : number },
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // handle request success
            //data contains the server's response
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // handle request failure
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="sample-form" action="myscript.php" method="get">
    <label for="number">Your number:</label>
    <input type="text" name="number" id="number" value="" />
    <label for="submit">Submit form</label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```

But at the end it depens on what you want to achieve. Hope i could help you a bit.

Comment: He doesn't want to use form tags.